# 32-bit Vegas Pro 10 on 64-bit Windows 8 - Any issues with this?

Tags: vegas-pro, windows

Yes, I know I should update my copy of Vegas, but it's not in the budget right now.

I have a copy of Vegas Pro 10 that I've been running on WinXP without problems.  Now I just got a new PC and it has Win8 on it.  Since VP10 is a 32-bit program, and Win8 is a 64-bit OS, I'm just curious if anyone has experienced any issues with running it on Win8?  Just things I should look out for, tips/workarounds I might need?  Or does it run as expected without any tweaking necessary?